# Como posso "pular" elementos de um array quando uso "list"?

Tags: php, lista

Tenho o seguinte `array`

```
$array = [25, 'Wallace', '26 anos', 'linguagens' => ['PHP', 'Python', 'C#']
```

Gostaria de usar a função `list` para poder capturar alguns elementos diretamente em variáveis, mais ou menos assim:

```
   list($id, $nome, $idade) = $array;
```

Porém eu gostaria de ignorar o primeiro elemento (que seria a variável `$id`), deixando apenas as seguintes variáveis: `$nome` e `$idade`.

Existe alguma maneira de "pular" um elemento do `array` ao criar as variáveis com `list`?

Não quero ter que fazer isso:

```
   list($id, $nome, $idade) = $array;

  unset($id);
```

E se eu quisesse pular 2 elementos do `array`? teria que dar `unset` em todas as primeiras variáveis?

Comment: Próxima pergunta, como pular o elemento 2 e 5 :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A opção mais é atribui o primeiro elemento do array a "nada" ou seja não definindo nenhuma variável.

```
list(, $nome, $idade) = $array;
```

Pode usar `array_slice()` para extrair os elementos que deseja usar em `list()`, o segundo argumento é a partir de qual elemento deve começar e o terceiro é a quantidade no caso dois nesse exemplo.

No PHP5.x `$nome` receberá "Wallace" e `$idade` "26" porém no PHP7 esse comportamento foi alterado funcinando na forma reversa.

```
$array = [25, 'Wallace', '26 anos', 'linguagens' => ['PHP', 'Python', 'C#']];
list($nome, $idade) =  array_slice($array,1, 2);
```

Comment: Sim, amiguinho. Mas eu pensei que você ia colocar a outra opção, hehehehehe. +1, boa alternativa

Comment: KKKKKKKKK, na hora que eu respondi ele atualizou, kkkkkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters LOL foi por uns 30 segundos de diferença, tava procurando essa outra maneira q vc falou hehe.

Comment: Deixa eu firular minha resposta para diferenciar

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento posso sim xD mas o manual aqui é bloqueado quero fazer um teste no https://3v4l.org/ p mostra o comportamento nas duas versões, só que vai ficar pro final da tarde ¬¬'.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pra php prefiro aquele outro link pq ele roda aquele código em quase todas as versões do php ai vc ve a diferença dos comportamentos. Conheço sim :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na documenta off line está assim "list() constructs can no longer be empty. The following are no longer allowed" e um dos exemplos é `list(,,) = $a;`

Comment: @rray realmente eu li errado :/

Answer (score 2):

Estava ansioso para alguém responder essa, mas tenho que dar uma palinha aqui.

O `list` no PHP suporta nativamente "pular" os elementos listados simplesmente não declarando nada onde normalmente estaria uma variável.

Ou seja, é necessário apenas fazer assim:

```
  list(, $nome, $idade) = [15, 'Wallace', '26 anos'];
```

Se você quer pular outros elementos, você pode fazer assim:

```
 list(,,$idade, $linguagens) = $array;
```

Ainda existem outras maneiras mais complexas como:

```
 list(,,$idade, list($php, $python)) = [15, 'Wallace', '25 anos', ['PHP', 'Python'])
```

Ou então

```
  list(,$nome,,$linguagens) = $array;
```